# RadioButtons in DataGridView Column VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, radio-button

Can anyone know how to add Radio Buttons in a Datagrid View Column?? I need three radio button in single cell..

Comment: update your code for datagridview here to get good answers

Comment: Yea.. I know. But i try to Edit Column property. There is only `datagridview checkbox column` and `datagridview combobox column` only. `Datagridview radiobutton column` not there. I am newbie to vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own cell and column for the `DataGridView`. Its a little bit tricky, but here you have all the steps from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -2):

Here I have a Simple Method Use a Radio Button Selected and
UnSelected Transparent PNG image

http://how2doinvbdotnet.blogspot.in/

check my Blog : how2doinvbdotnet.blogspot.in

```
Public Class Form1 Dim ColType(,) As
   Integer Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e
   As System.EventArgs) _ Handles MyBase.Load With DataGridView1
   .RowCount = 5 .ColumnCount = 3 For i As Integer = 0 To .RowCount - 1
   .Rows(i).Cells(2) = New DataGridViewImageCell
   .Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.Alignment =
   DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter .Rows(i).Cells(2).Value =
   My.Resources.RadioUnsel .Rows(i).Cells(2).Tag = 2 Next End With End
   Sub   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object,
   ByVal e As _System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles
   DataGridView1.CellClick With DataGridView1 If
   .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Tag = 2 Then For i As Integer
   = 0 To .RowCount - 1 If e.RowIndex <> i Then .Rows(i).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = My.Resources.RadioUnsel

Else
.Rows(i).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = My.Resources.RadioButtonSel
End If
Next
End If
End With
End Sub
End Class
```